# letsencrypt with nginx blacklabelops on azure

Tags: azure, nginx, lets-encrypt

I successfully got https://github.com/blacklabelops/letsencrypt and the nginx running on my virtual machine on azure. 
In Docker I hae now 2 containers. One with my go application running and being reachable on port 8080 on the web, one with the nginx container of blacklabelops. this one is binded to ports 80 and 443. I followed the tutorial "Letsencrypt and Nginx" on github for the steps 1-3 and replaced "http://yourserver" in step 3 with the url of my go application and port 8080 where I can reach it via http.

When I call https and the domain nothing happens. Ports 8080,443 and 80 are open in the azure network security group.

Can you give me a hint?

Update: I can post the commands _i performed here.
I have "my" application running on http://myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8080

I performed 1:

```
sudo docker run -d \
-p 80:80 \
-p 443:443 \
-e "SERVER1REVERSE_PROXY_LOCATION1=/" \
-e "SERVER1REVERSE_PROXY_PASS1=172.17.0.2" \
-e "SERVER1CERTIFICATE_DNAME=/CN=Chatbot/OU=Kundenservice/O=myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/L=Frankfurt/C=DE" \
-e "SERVER1HTTPS_ENABLED=true" \
--name nginx \
blacklabelops/nginx
```

Than I performed 2:

```
sudo docker run --rm \
-p 80:80 \
-p 443:443 \
-v letsencrypt_certificates:/etc/letsencrypt \
-e "LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mymail@azure.com" \
-e "LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN1=myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" \
blacklabelops/letsencrypt install
```

I did 3:

```
sudo docker volume create letsencrypt_challenges
```

And 4:

```
    -p 443:443 \
-p 80:80 \
-v letsencrypt_certificates:/etc/letsencrypt \
-v letsencrypt_challenges:/var/www/letsencrypt \
-e "NGINX_REDIRECT_PORT80=true" \
-e "SERVER1REVERSE_PROXY_LOCATION1=/" \
-e "SERVER1REVERSE_PROXY_PASS1=http://myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" \
-e "SERVER1HTTPS_ENABLED=true" \
-e "SERVER1HTTP_ENABLED=true" \
-e "SERVER1LETSENCRYPT_CERTIFICATES=true" \
-e "SERVER1CERTIFICATE_FILE=/etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/fullchain.pem" \
-e "SERVER1CERTIFICATE_KEY=/etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/privkey.pem" \
-e "SERVER1CERTIFICATE_TRUSTED=/etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/fullchain.pem" \
--name nginx \
blacklabelops/nginx
```

Comment: I recognized, that my nginx container exists after starting up. The reason is:

nginx: [emerg] host not found in resolver "run" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16

I googled, but I dindn't get along with a solution for that.

Comment: myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com is no valid domain. You do not own azure.com. Letsencrypt will not be able to give you a certificate. You need your own domain like www.yourhost.com or myapp.yourhost.com.

Comment: Also step 1 is obsolete when you do step 2. Omit step 1.